# How to reopen a previously closed windows form. "Cannot access a disposed Object"

Tags: c#, winforms, objectdisposedexception

I've read several things like this here but found no solution in my problem.

I'm sending data from form1 to my tempGraph form. Everything is OK not until I close my tempGraph form and try to reopen it. as i try to reopen it says `CANNOT ACCESS A DISPOSED OBJECT` which is now my problem.

How will I be able to open again my tempGraph?

This is my code for sending data to different forms like my tempGraph:

```
 public void SetText(string text)//Set values to my textboxes
{
    if (this.receive_tb.InvokeRequired)
    {   
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {  var controls = new TextBox[]
       {    wdirection_tb,
            wspeed_tb,
            humidity_tb,
            temperature_tb,
            rainin_tb,
            drainin_tb,
            pressure_tb,
            light_tb
        };
        data = text.Split(':');
        for (int index = 0; index < controls.Length && index < data.Length; index++) // This code segment Copy the data to TextBoxes
        {   
            TextBox control = controls[index];
            control.Text = data[index];
            //planning to pud the code for placing data to DataGridView here.
        }
            //or Place a code here to Call a UDF function that will start copying files to DataGridView
        //index1++; //it will count what row will be currently added by datas
        if (data.Length != 0)
        { datagridreport(temperature_tb.Text.ToString(), humidity_tb.Text.ToString(),     pressure_tb.Text.ToString());  }  


        //sending of data to each graph. THIS CODE SENDS DATA TO OTHER FORMS
        tempG.temp.Text = temperature_tb.Text;
        humdidG.humid.Text = humidity_tb.Text;
        pressG.Text = pressure_tb.Text;


        //updating textbox message buffer
        this.receive_tb.Text += text;
        this.receive_tb.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Here are my codes in opening the tempGraph located in my `form1`:

```
private void temperatureToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{            
    tempG.Show();
}
```

and I close my tempG/tempGraph using the X button located in the upper right or closing it using a button with the following command:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    TempGraph.ActiveForm.Close();
}
```

Note: When I reopen my tempGraph after closing it the error occurs.

Comment: i actually was be able to reopen it by adding this code "TempGraph tempG = new TempGraph();" in my private void temperatureToolStripMenuItem_Click. But the problem is i cant send anydata to my graphforms.

Comment: Calling `Close` on a `Form` will dispose the underlying resources of the `Form` so it cannot be shown again, calling `Hide` will make the `Form` no longer visible but not dispose of the underlying resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you have stored the reference to the current `tempGraph` form in a global variable and when you close the current instance that variable still holds a reference to a now disposed object.

The solution is to get the closed event in you main form and reset to null the global variable.

So suppose to change you menu click to

```
private void temperatureToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{            
    if(tempG == null)
    {
        tempG = new tempGraph();
        tempG.FormClosed += MyGraphFormClosed;
    }
    tempG.Show();                
}
```

and add the following event handler in your main form

```
private void MyGraphFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    tempG = null;
}
```

Now, when the `tempGraph` form instance referenced by `tempG` is closed you will be notified and you could set the global variable `tempG` to null. Of course now you need to check everywhere before using that variable but when you call tempG.Show() you are sure to have it point to a correctly NON DISPOSED instance.

Comment: We should really understand in which point this exception is raised. Do you have code in the tempGraph form executed at Constructor/Load/Activate time? Can you use the debugger to follow step by step what happen when you call Show or when you call SetText?

Comment: im calling setText to parse data into different textboxes after my function read(). This Read function is the one fetches data from my port.

Comment: In my tempGraph form. im actually creating a graph in there using zed and everything is okey and its running in a timer function also im utilizing a TempGraph_Load function to set the graph settings

Comment: Are you sure the message is _a disposed FILE_? Usually is _a disposed object_

Comment: im getting the point.... we can avoid disposed object by simple creating a new instance of tempG by initializing it again. but the problem is when we initialized it again the data will not the send since there is a new tempG and the tempG im my function setText is still the old tempG.

Comment: @Solem It sounds like you need to not be closing the form in the first place, perhaps you really should just be hiding it. [See my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804851/how-to-reopen-a-previously-closed-windows-form-cannot-access-a-disposed-object#comment44019935_27804851) to the original question.

Comment: hmmm ill be trying your advices guys. Maybe i should disable the "temperatureToolStripMenuItem_Click" if the port is still close to avoid the user from opening the tempGraph form and so i could use the hide function when the port is already open. right?

Comment: Looking at your SetText. humidG and pressG are other forms with the same usage pattern of your tempG? If yes do you apply the same pattern used for tempG?

Comment: Plus one million for the concise, elegant, and correct, answer to the OP's (and my) problem!